# CakePHP + Rackspace index.php mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, rackspace-cloud

I've just set up a Rackspace server, everything is running properly. I have uploaded all my CakePHP code to rackspace. `phpinfo()` is showing mod_rewrite enabled.

`index.php` is creating a problem for me (http://testname.com/index.php/home). On my test site, same code is working properly without any error (or redirection problem) and without `index.php` in URL.

From support document, mod_rewrite changes are applied in `.htaccess` file.
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/frequently-asked-question/why-is-modrewrite-not-working-on-my-site

Any suggestions, what are the configurations are required on Rackspace so that my website can be accessed without `index.php` in URL?

Comment: have you tried adding `RewriteBase` in htaccess files as described in link from the question, mainly putting `RewriteBase /my_site_dir` in htacess files right after `RewriteEngine On` ?

Comment: @dav Yes, i have added it to htaccess